Access GitHub Packages from k8s (Personal Access Token alternative)
You can use GitHub Packages as docker registry.
However, if it is private, you need to authorize your k8s cluster for pulling.
There is an option to create a k8s docker-registry secret using PAT(Personal Access Token).
While working fine for test/dev stuff I'm curious about the correct way to do it for a production. I'm not sure that way when a DevOps creates PAT and uses it for an environment configuration is the best and optimal. The problem I see here -> if the person leaves an organisation and we terminate the access, the token will not work and we will have an issue.
Any suggestions about a better way?
I've thought about using system tokens which are available during GitHub Actions CI/CD, however, they are short-term, and if you need to scale your deployment for example after GitHub Action is finished it probably will fail.

You should create an organization on GitHub to manage repos and packages, instead of a personal one, and then you are not blocked by one user's departure.

Whether it possible to create an access token for an organisation? I believe with organisation your PAT will lose an access once you removed from the org. So I'm looking for PAT alternative

But another user from that organization can generate a new PAT and replace the expired one. So, for the organization itself, business can continue.

It is quite clear, however I am looking for an alternative. When you don't need interup the flow.

You could create a new user on GitHub and add it to your organization as service user. Its only meaning will be to be used in your Org automations, generating a PAT shared in your necessary workflows, with the adapted permissions.

Good point also considered it.
